# Why are changes made with custom javascript not being registered

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom javascript that autofills a CharField when I check a checkbox but when I click "Save" the text from the CharField doesn't save to the database, it's empty. How can I fix this?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
(function () {
    django.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(django.jQuery('#id_main_product'))

        django.jQuery('#id_main_product').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                django.jQuery('#id_name').val(django.jQuery('#id_category :selected').text())
                django.jQuery('#id_name').prop("disabled", true)
            }
            else {
                console.log('unchecked')
            }

        })
    })
})(django.jQuery);
```

});